# Radio Button implemetation with GSRadioButtonSetController not changing state in reference to color

Tags: iphone, ios, radio-button

I am using GSRadioButtonSetController for the radio button implementation...I created two buttons and included in IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttonCollection....then I included GSRadioButtonSetController.h and GSRadioButtonSetController.m file to my project. Then to my viewdidload I added

```
// Instantiate your GSRadioButtonSetController object
self.radioButtonSetController = [[GSRadioButtonSetController alloc] init];

// Set its delegate to your view controller
self.radioButtonSetController.delegate = self;

// Set its buttons property to an array of buttons that you've
// created previously.
self.radioButtonSetController.buttons = buttonCollection;
```

and then I put

```
- (void)radioButtonSetController:(GSRadioButtonSetController *)controller
      didSelectButtonAtIndex:(NSUInteger)selectedIndex
{

//implemetation


 }
```

There are tow image for the button...one for the select state and 2nd for the deselcetd state....the code is giving me indexes however I dont know how to change to image dynamically so that user know which one is selected and which one is not...

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you create the buttons to add to `buttonCollection',  set image to buttons, like:

```
[button_1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_button_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button_1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_button_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

it worked for me